# SQL subquery help (using agregate functions I believe)

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

[image]

I'm doing homework for my SQL query class and I'm stuck on a subquery. I need to list by warehouse the count of the number of items that have an on hand amount less than 20 items. And I need to ONLY display the warehouses that have more than one item with less than 20 on hand. Here is what I have:

```
select warehouse, on_hand, description
from part
where on_hand < 20 and 
(   select count(description)
    from part
    group by warehouse
)
order by warehouse;
```

What I need help with is the subquery part (if I need one, subqueries are what I struggle with). I don't necessarily want a straight-up answer, but help, like hints and direction.

Comment: Search for "group by having", you will get lot of help.

Comment: Is there only one table?

Comment: Please post your full table structure

Comment: I am only using 1 table for this question, yes

Comment: Can you supply us with the exact table schema as part of your question?

Comment: Table = part ---  columns = part_num, description, on_hand, class, warehouse, price   ---  is this what you guys mean by table schema?

Comment: the `on_hand` column, what type is it? do you have to simply count the total rows for each warehouse or do you need to sum the `on_hand` values?

Comment: the on_hand column is the number of that item that is currently in the warehouse. I need a statement that lists if on_hand < 20 and each  warehouse that has 2 or more individual items with < 20

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, since you don't want someone to do all the work for you, and you want to use a subquery, you could try the following:

```
select col1, total_items 
from
(   select col1, 
    sum(col2) as total_items
    from part
    group by col1
) 
where total_items < 20 and total_items > 0
order by total_items;
```

Notice that you'd treat the subquery as a 'table'...

Now, using the HAVING clause:

```
select warehouse, count(description)
from part
where on_hand < 20
group by warehouse 
having count(description) > 1
order by warehouse;
```

You can learn more about this clause [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp).

Comment: Is there a way to do without a subquery? I only assumed that I needed a subquery because this was the last (hardest) question on a homework assignment and my professor usually makes that one the hardest/longest

Comment: you could achieve the same using the HAVING clause, read more about it [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_having.asp)

Comment: select warehouse, on_hand, description
from part
group by description
having (select count(description) from part where on_hand < 20 group by warehouse) > 1
order by warehouse;

Comment: I couldn't figure out how to get yours above to work, but I used it to try to get my own to work. Is there anyway you can help me to "refine" what I have just above to work?

Answer (score 0):

```
select warehouse, count(description)
from part
where on_hand < 20
group by warehouse 
having count(description) > 1
order by warehouse;
```

Does this work? The question says "List by warehouse the count of the number of items that have an on hand amount less than 20 items.  Only display those warehouses that have more than one item that is less than 20 on hand." and this output gives warehouse2 having 2 items under 20, and warehouse3 having 2 items under 20 count. It looks correct when I check manually against

```
select warehouse, count(description)
from part
where on_hand < 20
```

Comment: yeah, looks fine. I've updated my answer, take a look... =)

Comment: Ah hah! Playing around with your initial script and looking up examples using group by and having helped. Thanks for the help!